# Multiple Selectors in jQuery UI Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
$("#dialog-cust-grp,#dialog-cust-nm").dialog({
         open: function(event, ui) {
                 $("a.ui-dialog-titlebar-close").remove();
               },
         bgiframe: true,autoOpen: false,closeOnEscape: false,
         resizable: false,modal: true,show: "drop",hide: "drop",                
         draggable: false,zIndex: 10000,
         buttons: {'Ok': function() {$(this).dialog("close");
                    if (selector is #dialog-cust-nm){
                      alert(“hello....”);
                    }
         }
   });
```

Based on the above code, which has two different selectors, i.e. `$("#dialog-cust-grp,#dialog-cust-nm")` is there a way of checking which selector is actually being used in the `.dialog()` call as I need a means of doing something like this above, i.e.

```
If (selector is #dialog-cust-nm){
  alert(“hello....”);
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call atribut value by [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
if ($(this).attr("id") == "dialog-cust-nm") {
   alert(“hello....”);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .[is()](http://docs.jquery.com/Is) to check if an element mathces a selector.

```
if ($(this).is("#dialog-cust-nm")){
    alert(“hello....”);
}
```